# PHP add whitespaces in string with an URL

Tags: php, laravel, string, amazon-s3, ffmpeg

**Problem**

I have a temporary url to access an object from AWS-S3

```
$source = "http://mybucket...";
```

If I do a var_dump($source) it shows me the correct URL

```
string(407) "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
```

So I try to use this url in a ffmpeg command in this way (double quotes are required in ffmpeg)

```
$cmd = 'ffmpeg -i "' . $source . '" ...
shell_exec($cmd);
```

This do not work, and when I do a var_dump($cmd) the url shows like this (whitespace beetween `https:` and the `//` )

```
 "https: //mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
```

It works fine when I specify the url with the S3 protocol

```
"s3://mybucket...."
```

So maybe the problem is with the https protocol

**What I tried**(It didn't work)

- I tried `$url = str_replace(' ', '', $source);`
- I tried `$url = str_replace('%20', '', $source);`
- I tried `$url = str_replace('https: //', 'https://', $source);`
- I tried `$url = preg_replace("/\s+/", "", $source);`
- I tried `addslashes($source)` instead `'"' . $source . '"'`
- I tried `$url = escapeshellarg($source);`

**What I'm using**

- Php 7
- Laravel 4
- AWS-S3

Comment: How about `$cmd= str_replace(': // ', '://', $cmd);` There is no reason I can see why that space should suddenly appear

Comment: What you get the output with `$url = str_replace(' ', '', $source);` ???

Comment: I also tried this way @AntG and I have the same result.

Comment: I have the same result @sta, the string with the whitespace `"https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."´

Comment: Above method should work, if it just a whitespace. I think you got `https:%20//`, if so then you may try `$url = str_replace('%20', '', $source);`

Comment: I have tried that and it has also failed @sta

Comment: If your output is `https: //mybucket` then this should work `$url = str_replace(' ', '', $source);`

Comment: Unfortunately that method doesn't work, I can send you snapshots @sta

Comment: use `dd()` function of laravel instead of `var_dump()`. I don't think this type of error can occur. You neede to restart you apache server and try again.

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet, I also tried `$url = escapeshellarg($source);` @sta

Comment: Still no luck???

Comment: @sta Nothing works, looks like a php bug

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use `sprintf`?!
I tried and works like champ!

```
$source = "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/...";
$cmd = sprintf('ffmpeg -i "%s"', $source);

$array = [
    'source' => $source,
    'cmd' => $cmd
];

echo '<pre>'; print_r($array); echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>'; var_dump($array); echo '</pre>';
```

and result is:

```
Array
(
    [source] => https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/...
    [cmd] => ffmpeg -i "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
)
array(2) {
  ["source"]=>
  string(45) "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/..."
  ["cmd"]=>
  string(57) "ffmpeg -i "https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/storage/...""
}
```